# Specific heat capacity in gas vs solid

Tags: solid-state-physics, thermal-conductivity, gas

If in general the specific heat capacity is low in gas then why doesn't it raise it's temperature more quickly compared to a solid that is given similar conditions as to the gas. (By the reason of the definition  of s.h.c. is "heat that should be transferred in order to change an unit temperature in 1 kg" )if so then by giving similar heat energy to both solid and gas , gas should have the high temperature .why not? Please explain

Answer (score 1):

"Specific heat capacity" is defined as the amount of heat absorbed or released by an unit mass of a substance when it's temperature changes by one unit. Yeah you are right, specific heat capacity for gases is low because less amount of heat supplied can change it's temperature by one unit whereas solids require more heating for it's temperature to change by one unit.

$$S = \frac{\delta Q}{m\,\delta T}$$

Here is some data regarding specific heat capacities of water in it's different states,

$$\mathrm {Steam} : 2010\,J/ kg\,°C$$
$$\mathrm {Ice} : 2090\,J/ kg\,°C$$
$$\mathrm {Water(liquid)} : 4200\,J/ kg\,°C$$

You could see that heat capacity for steam is lower than the ice, but the difference is not that significant in this case,

The trends in specific heat capacity has lots of exceptions but depends on the properties(such as hydrogen bonding and dipole interactions) of the subsatance.

But in general, the order of specific heat capacity for different states is
$$Gas<Solid<Liquid$$

When we consider ideal states of matter, liquids generaly absorb or release more heat(for a unit change in temperature) because they exchange energy through both translational and vibrational modes whereas gases and solids do so only by translational and vibrational respectively.

Comment: Then when the same amount of is supplied  to both states , how do solids change temperature

Comment: Sorry couldn't complete the above comment...how do solids rises temperature more than gas

Comment: If that is the case i would like to edit my answer

Comment: Thank you......

Comment: you could accept the answer if it really satisfied you by clicking the tick mark

Comment: or by upvoting if you can

Comment: Asking out of curiosity ..cuz I'm quite new to stack exchange. What does upvoting do? I have no idea about it.

Comment: upvoting increases the reputation of the person who answered, the more reputation one has, the more he or she can be trusted. Reputation also gives you some special abilities which you can see in the help section